# Android SQLite DB Becomes Corrupt

Tags: android, sqlite

This is an issue that has been plaguing me for a while now. I am trying to use SQLite DBs to store information in my application. Once I open a DB, I close it right after I'm finished. Here is a rough overview of what I do:

```
getWriteableDB;
// Perform DB Operations
closeDB;
```

This works great, most of the time. Occasionally, the DB files become corrupt and it has to delete them and create a new one. On top of that, sometimes it fails when creating a new DB with a "Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database".

I'm really stumped by all of this as I thought SQLite was supposed to be pretty dependable. It's been more trouble than it's worth in my experience, but perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Also, when my application has multiple tables, I've begun to put only one table in each DB so that if one table operation messes up, it only corrupts that table's information and not any other tables information.

Thanks,

groomsy

Comment: I've found that *never* closing the DB makes things more reliable &mdash; at least in a `ContentProvider`.

If you have just one instance of `SQLiteDatabase` open, whether you retrieve it via getReadable or getWritable, it'll handle concurrent access nicely for you.  At least in ContentProviders, there's no real reason to close the DB, as all related handles should be closed when the process containing the provider dies.

Comment: If you don't close the DB, you get nasty error messages about a Leak being created. Maybe there's a better way of handling that though.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess it depends on the context you're opening the DB in, but then I've only done this from a ContentProvider. The only time I get "leak" warnings is when I forget to close a Cursor or SQLiteStatement.

Comment: One option is to use another database, such as the H2 database. I'm not saying H2 is generally more stable than SQLite (I really don't know that), I only wanted to let you know you _could_ use it. Disclaimer: I'm the main author of the H2 database...: http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

Comment: This would more then double the size of my (carefully optimised) apk. No, thanks.